# Populate table with info from another (maybe via join)

Tags: mysql

On a MySQL database, I have two tables that have those columns:
    table a: id_a email firstname lastname
     table b: id_b email

I want to add corresponding id from table a to new column in table b based on email, using a MySQL query.

So it would look like this:
    table a: id_a email firstname lastname
     table b: id_b email **id_a**

Is it something that’s possible? What would such a code look like?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableA a
JOIN tableB b
   ON a.email = b.email
SET b.id_a = a.id_a
```

Comment: exactly what I needed.
(had to create a column Id_a first, though, but that was easy).

Many many thanks for your quick answer!!!